# How to create a RedShift table using Spark?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-redshift

This works in Spark:

```
df =  spark.read \
  .format('jdbc') \
  .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://redshift-cluster-xyz.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev") \
  .option("user", "myuser") \
  .option("password", "mypass") \
  .option("query", "select distinct(tablename) from pg_table_def where schemaname = 'public' ") \
  .load().show()
```

This fails:

```
spark.read \
  .format('jdbc') \
  .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://redshift-cluster-xyz.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev") \
  .option("user", "myuser") \
  .option("password", "mypass") \
  .option("query", 'CREATE TABLE product (c1 real) ') \
  .load()
```

Getting error:
`Caused by: com.amazon.support.exceptions.ErrorException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "CREATE"`

I tried with double quotes as well.

How to create a table in Redshift using Spark with specifying data type?

Comment: use dbtable option not query, that is for reading data I think.

Comment: This is not true. You can run the query like this. The problem was network and VPC.

Comment: @Joe: I am trying to create tables from existing tables inside redshift via spark using CTAS statement and it's throwing this error. Any pointers?